# EF include not working. Missing data when selecting to new object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I think I'm misunderstanding something about EF Includes or lazy-loading or perhaps I haven't set my Entities up correctly.

If I have this query, it works as expected. I get a list of products with their associated productOptions

```
var prodQuery = db.Products
    .Include("ProductOptions")
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(p =>
       p.CategoryId == category.Id
       && p.Active && !p.Deleted
       && p.ProductOptions.Any(po => po.Active && !po.Deleted)
    ).ToList();
```

However, when I try to select them to DTO's... The products contain no ProductOptions. Somehow they're not being included

```
 var products = db.Products
    .Include("ProductOptions")
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(p =>
       p.CategoryId == category.Id
       && p.Active && !p.Deleted
       && p.ProductOptions.Any(po => po.Active && !po.Deleted))
    .Select(p =>
       new ProductDTO
       {
           Id = p.Id,
           Name = p.Name,
           Description = p.Description,
           ProductOptionDTOs = p.ProductOptions
               .Where(po => po.Active && !po.Deleted)
               .Select(po =>
                   new ProductOptionDTO
                   {
                       Id = po.Id,
                       Name = po.Name,
                       Price = po.Price
                   }
               ).ToList()
       }
    ).ToList();
```

Here are my Entities... Removed non-relevant properties for brevity

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductOption> ProductOptions { get; set; }
}

public class ProductOption
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone help me understand I'm missing ProductOptions in my second query?

**My mistake everyone, no longer a problem. Thanks for all your help**

After investigating everyone's suggestions and going through my code I found I had made a mistake in my ProductDTO (the declaration for the ProductOptionDTOs property) that was silently failing and causing ProductOptionDTOs to be null without errors.

I got suspicious of my DTO after I tested the sql being generated by EF, and found the sql was correctly returning the right data, therefore I presumed there must have been a problem mapping it back to the DTO.

So it turns out it would have been critical to show you guys my DTO's in the first place even though I dismissed that idea

Fixed :)

Comment: can you try without .AsNoTracking()? I only use it to implicitly EXCLUDE my navigation properties

Comment: @mejobloggs If only as a test try changing public ICollection<ProductOption> ProductOptions { get; set; } to public List<ProductOptionDTO> ProductOptions { get; set; }

Comment: @DevilSuichiro same result without AsNoTracking

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
public ICollection<ProductOption> ProductOptions { get; set; }

ProductOptions = p.ProductOptions
                  .Where(po => po.Active && !po.Deleted)
                  .Select(po =>
                  new ProductOptionDTO
                  {
                      Id = po.Id,
                      Name = po.Name,
                      Price = po.Price
                  }).ToList()
```

Notice the difference with

```
new ProductOptionDTO
```

and the type of the ProductOptions member in your class

```
ICollection<ProductOption>
```

so try changing

```
public ICollection<ProductOption> ProductOptions { get; set; }

public ICollection<ProductOptionDTO> ProductOptions { get; set; }
```

and change the name of your 'ProductOption' class to 'ProductOptionDTO':

```
public class ProductOption
```

to

```
public class ProductOptionDTO
```

also shouldn't your 'Product' class be changed as follows?

```
public class Product
```

be

```
public class ProductDTO
```

**Edit:** Try this query expression if only as a test...

```
var products = (from p in db.Products
               where p.CategoryId == category.Id
               && p.Active && !p.Deleted
               && p.ProductOptions.Any(po => po.Active && !po.Deleted)
               select new ProductDTO
                {
                   Id = p.Id,
                   Name = p.Name,
                   Description = p.Description,
                   ProductOptionDTOs = (from po in p.ProductOptions
                                        where po.Active
                                        && !po.Deleted
                                        select new ProductOptionDTO
                                        {
                                            Id = po.Id,
                                            Name = po.Name,
                                            Price = po.Price
                                        }).ToList() 
                }).ToList()
```

**EDIT2:** If the above doesn't work then try this where you specify the joining properties...

```
var products = (from p in db.Products
               where p.CategoryId == category.Id
               && p.Active && !p.Deleted
               && p.ProductOptions.Any(po => po.Active && !po.Deleted)
               select new ProductDTO
                {
                   Id = p.Id,
                   Name = p.Name,
                   Description = p.Description,
                   ProductOptionDTOs = (from po in db.ProductOptions
                                        where po.ProductId == p.ProductId
                                        && po.Active
                                        && !po.Deleted
                                        select new ProductOptionDTO
                                        {
                                            Id = po.Id,
                                            Name = po.Name,
                                            Price = po.Price
                                        }).ToList() 
                }).ToList()
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I don't think that's the issue. I've edited for clarity. I'm selecting things as a new list to the DTO's. I haven't shown the DTO classes because I don't think they're relevant as it's the actual underlying Entities that EF uses for joins etc

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Include` has no effect when executing complex query.
One way to fix this is to use so-called `projection`. It's just a dynamic type that is used within query (`new {...}`).

Try something like this:

```
var products = db.Products
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(p =>
        p.CategoryId == category.Id
        && p.Active && !p.Deleted
        && p.ProductOptions.Any(po => po.Active && !po.Deleted))
    .Select(p =>
        new
        {
            product = p,
            options = p.ProductOptions.Where(po => po.Active && !po.Deleted)
        }
    )
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(s =>
        new ProductDTO
        {
            Id = s.product.Id,
            Name = s.product.Name,
            Description = s.product.Description,
            ProductOptionDTOs = s.options
                .Select(po =>
                    new ProductOptionDTO
                    {
                        Id = po.Id,
                        Name = po.Name,
                        Price = po.Price
                    }
                )
        }
    );
```